# Trying to add data from Firebase into a flatlist

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, flatlist

Hi I'm very new to react and firebase and have been following a few tutorials but I am fairly lost. I'm struggling to add data from my firebase database into my flatlist. I am getting the error [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _firestore.doc.data is not a function. (In '_firestore.doc.data()', '_firestore.doc.data' is undefined)] and don't know what to do next?

```
`const getQuiz = async () => {
    const ref = db.collection('QuizzesList');
    const doc = await ref.get();
    const quizObject = doc.data();
    const newQuiz = [...quizzes, {name: quizObject.name, 
description:quizObject.description,
        screenName:quizObject.screenName, image:quizObject.image}]
    setQuizzes(newQuiz)
}
useEffect(()=> {
    getQuiz();
}, [])

const Item = ({name,description,screenName,image}) => (
    <View style={searchScreen.quizContainer}>
        <ImageBackground
            source={image}
            style={searchScreen.image}
        />

        <View style={searchScreen.titles}>
            <Text style={searchScreen.title}>{name}</Text>
            <Text style={searchScreen.subtitle}>{description}&nbsp; 
</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={searchScreen.buttonsContainer} >
            <StyledButton
                content={"Cychwyn y Cwis"}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate(screenName)}/>
        </View>


    </View>
 );

 const renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <Item name={item.name} description={item.description} screenName= 
{item.screenName} image={item.image}/>
)

return(
    <View style={searchScreen.quizContainer}>
        <FlatList
            data={quizzes}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}

            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            snapToAlignment={'start'}
            decelerationRate={'fast'}
            snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').height}
        />
    </View>
)}`
```

My code after trying the answer provided :

```
const getQuiz = async () => {
    const ref = db.collection('QuizzesList');
    const snapshot = await ref.get();
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const quizObject = doc.data();
        const newQuiz = [...quizzes, {name: quizObject.name, 
description:quizObject.description,
            screenName:quizObject.screenName, 
image:quizObject.image}]
        setQuizzes(newQuiz)
    })
useEffect(()=> {
    getQuiz();
}, [])
```

The new Error Message :

```
'[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: 
_firebaseConfig.db.collection is 
not a function. (In '_firebaseConfig.db.collection('QuizzesList')', 
'_firebaseConfig.db.collection' is undefine
d)]
at node_modules\@firebase\webchannel-wrapper\dist\index.js:89:122 in 
n.Ia
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:190:16 in 
PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:15 in 
callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:212:38 in enqueue
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:239:8 in exports.async
at node_modules\@firebase\webchannel-wrapper\dist\index.js:89:94 in 
<anonymous>
at node_modules\@firebase\webchannel-wrapper\dist\index.js:90:183 in 
ie
at node_modules\react- 
native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:19280:25 in invokePassiveEffectCreate
at node_modules\react- 
native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:93:4 
in invokeGuardedCallbackProd
at node_modules\react- 
native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:318:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
at node_modules\react- 
native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:19362:29 in flushPassiveEffectsImpl
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:468:23 in 
unstable_runWithPriority
at node_modules\react- 
native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js:19123:29 in scheduleCallback$argument_1
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:417:41 in 
workLoop
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:390:21 in 
flushWork
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:55:17 in 
_flushCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 
in 
_callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:379:16 
in 
callTimers
at node_modules\react-
```

native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-
native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:6 in
__guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-
native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-
native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:4 in
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue '

And im not sure if this helps but I tried to pull the data from the firebase database not in a flatlist and it works (see below)

```
export default function Testread({navigation}) {
const [newName,setNewName] =useState("")
const [newDesc] =useState(0)
const [newScreenName] =useState("")
const [newImage] =useState("")
const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);
const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "QuizzesList")

const createUser = async () => {
    await addDoc(usersCollectionRef, {name: newName, description: newDesc,image: newImage,screenName:newScreenName})
}

useEffect(() =>{
    const getUsers = async () => {

        const data = await getDocs(usersCollectionRef)
        setUsers(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
        console.warn("asdadsffgsAGFsgSDGf")

    }
    getUsers()
}, [])
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <CustomInput placeholder="Username"  setValue={setNewName}/>
            <CustomInput placeholder="Age"/>
        <SubmitButton onPress={createUser} text="Create"/>

        {users.map((users) => {return <View>
            <Text>Name:{users.name}</Text>
            <Text>Age:{users.description}</Text>
            <Image style={quizScreen.picture} source={users.image} />
            <Text>ScreenName: {users.screenName}</Text>
        </View>})}
    </View>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `get` on a `CollectionReference`, which means you get back all documents in that collection in a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). And a query snapshot doesn't have a `data` property, which explains the errors.

To get the documents from the snapshot, loop over its `docs` property, with something like:

```
const ref = db.collection('QuizzesList');
const snapshot = await ref.get();
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const quizObject = doc.data();
  ...
})
```

Comment: I have just tried this and changed the original post to reflect this change and still getting the same error. And I dont know what to do?

Comment: Getting the same error on the changed code seems unlikely. Can you copy/paste the error message and possibly stack trace. But also: please don't modify the existing code in your question, as now my answer makes no sense anymore. If you still have problems after making the change, at worst make an update *under* your initial problem.

Comment: I Cant fit the whole error message here. However heres the start : [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _firebaseConfig.db.collection is not a function. (In '_firebaseConfig.db.collection('QuizzesList')', '_firebaseConfig.db.collection' is undefine
d)]
at node_modules\@firebase\webchannel-wrapper\dist\index.js:89:122 in n.Ia
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke

Comment: Don't try to put the information in a comment please. Instead: 1) roll back your question to its original content, 2) now add a section at the bottom showing what you did with the code in my answer, and the new error message you get (as this is a quite different error message than you had before).

Comment: Sorry very new to stack overflow. Ive done that now